# Paypal displaying an error while submiting webform paypal

Tags: webforms, payment-gateways

I am using Webform paypal module with webform for donation purpose. I have added paypal button and configured it as donation button. I have inputted correct button id which I have collected from paypal site.

All set well, but while I am trying to submit this form I will be redirected to test site with following error.

[image]

While I am debugging this I am founding url as following:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=xxxxxxxx&custom=http%3A//xxx.xxx.xxxx/submission/20

If anyone has an idea how to solve the above paypal error, the please let me know.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Webform Paypal issue queue to see if anyone else has experienced the same problem?

Comment: Yes.. I go through all this problem. but i didn't find any similar one or one from which i can get solution.

Comment: Have you tried editing the paypal payment settings and making it live to see if it still happens when you arent using the sandbox?

Comment: Actually.. what i did is, i have look through the url triggered after my donation button clicked. in that.. it should be like xclickdonation or xclick-donation like this. bt it is not same.  So my doubt is, is webform paypal module generating a different url as i am using it in form?